# Delete data on base of selected checkbox ids laravel 5.3

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am getting id's currently i an alert i want to post these id's to **destroyAll** method in my userController
here is my method through which i am getting id's in alert

```
function deleteAll () {
    var checkedValues = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    alert(checkedValues);
}
```

i want to post these values through ajax and delete there
**route** is as

```
Route::post('/user-management/user/destroyAll', 'UserController@destroyAll');
```

in destroyall method i also want to explode **,** and minus head checkbox value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use ajax:

```
    $.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        url     : "{{ url('/user-management/user/destroyAll') }}",
        data    : {ids: checkedValues, _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
        success : function (response) {
            console.log('Success', response);
        },
        error   : function (response) {
            console.log('Error', response);
        },
        dataType: "JSON"
    });
```

and then catch ids in controller:

```
public function destroyAll(Request $request)
{
    // get ids
    $ids = $request->input('ids');

    // remove first
    array_shift($ids);

    // delete users with id
    return User::whereIn('id', $ids)->delete();
}
```

Comment: what is `array_shift($ids);` used for?

Comment: It will remove first element of array, because OP asked "and minus head checkbox value" :)

Comment: @GiedriusKiršys please can you add whole method deleteAll clearly and update your answer please

Answer (score 0):

Join your values to a string add them to a hidden input and in your controller you do a whereIn function to get all the users and delete them :

html:

```
<input type="hidden">
```

js:

```
$('input[type="hidden"]').val(checkedValues.join(','));
```

php:

```
public function destroyAll(Request $request)
        {
            $checkedValues = explode(','$request->input("checkedValues"));
            $user = User::whereIn('id',$checkedValues);
            $user->delete();
            //redirect back to the page after delete 
        }
```

refine your selector to not select the first one:

```
checkedValues = $('input:checkbox:checked:not(:first)')
```

Comment: how will i come to destroyAll method ? @madalin ivascu

Comment: you use a form with that hidden input filed in it

Comment: this js will be after  `alert(checkedValues);` ? @madalin ivascu

Comment: just take it logically where will you put it? before the variable is initiated or after?

Comment: Don'y know sir that's why asking  @madalin ivascu